# How to create template for pull request in TFS

Tags: git, tfs, pull-request

Is it possible to create template for pull request from `tfs-git`?

Something similar to what we have in [github](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository/).

Answer (score 1):

You can install this extension in the marketplace : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cschleiden.prtemplates#overview

Github link : https://github.com/cschleiden/vsts-pr-templates

Answer (score 0):

Not that I can see:

- [no suggestion on VSTS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services?query=template%20commit) (you can only [associate a commit to a work item](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/4038344-associate-a-git-commit-with-a-work-item))
- you could use the [local config `commit.template`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-committemplate) as [illustrated here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/better-commit-messages-with-a-gitmessage-template), but that is a manual process.
- for git-tfs, the [`rcheckin`](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/commands/rcheckin.md) command has [some features to add special field to a commit message](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/special-actions-in-commit-messages.md), but nothing automated.

You would need to put in place a pre-receive hook on the server side to enforce any commit message policy.

Comment: I don't  want if for commit. I want it for PR description template. For example have a look at link :
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository/

Comment: @lalit I am not aware of such a feature on the server side. which is why I mentioned it on the client side, for commit messages.